# Vector print duplicate Values

Tags: c++

I've written a program in C++ to print out a vector of pointers to my classes `Vehicle` is a parent class for `Car`.
All the functions work properly yet the program itself prints wrong values, changing them after all iterations of the loop.
Here's the code:

```
int main() {
std::vector<Vehicle *> vehs;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::string Id;
    std::cout << "Id: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, Id);

    std::string Marka;
    std::cout << "Marka: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, Marka);

    double Par;
    std::cout << "Parametr: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Par;
    getchar();

    Car car(Id, Marka, Par);
    vehs.push_back(&car);

    std::cout << to_string(vehs.cbegin(), vehs.cend());

}
```

And the result is as follows:

```
Id:
A
Marka:
A
Parametr:
1
A : A
Id:
B
Marka:
B
Parametr:
2
B : B
B : B
Id:
C
Marka:
C
Parametr:
3
C : C
C : C
C : C
```

As you can see, the contents of `vehs` change even, if I do not want them to.

The `to_string` looks like that:

```
std::string to_string (const Vehicle& vehicle){
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << vehicle.getId() << " : "<< vehicle.getBrand();
return oss.str();
}


std::string to_string(std::vector<Vehicle*>::const_iterator vehicles_begin,
std::vector<Vehicle*>::const_iterator vehicles_end){
std::ostringstream  oss;
for(auto it = vehicles_begin; it!= vehicles_end; it++ ){
    oss << to_string(**it) << std::endl;
}
return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you call `to_string` in every loop iteration but after the loop has finished. So you have posted imaginary code unrelated to your questrion.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the code is nothing but imaginary, and `to_string` calls after every iteration.

Comment: @FilipFrey: Well, it's still not an MCVE, because both class definitions are missing (not to mention all the missing `#include`s).

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, I am sorry - this is my first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Car car(Id, Marka, Par);
vehs.push_back(&car);
```

You can not store pointers to local objects as these objects are destroyed once you leave the scope (so every time where your loop ends).

Instead you can use dynamic memory allocation for example this way:

```
Car *car = new Car(Id, Marka, Par);
vehs.push_back(car);
```

Of course please do not forget to destroy all of the objects with delete!
On the other hand, if you like, you can use std::shared_ptr (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) which will release the memory for you by itself :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see where he's leaving scope. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Can you please tell me more precisely how to do that?

Comment: I edited the answer so it also answers yours questions

Comment: @GreatBigBore: The OP probably posted bogus code. In the real code, the `to_string` call likely happens outside of the loop, and the answerer silently assumed that. I guess.

Comment: Both of your alternatives are bad. `std::uniqe_ptr` should be used by default if dynamic allocation cannot be avoided altogether.

Comment: @noonespecial thanks a lot!

Comment: @FilipFrey I hope it helps. Please do not forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem! Thanks! :)